# How to properly import RecyclerView in Android Studio in 2019?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, import

Android Studio pretends that it doesn't know RecyclerView class. I know it does.
I tried advices on the Internet (they're telling to add proper version of RecyclerView in gradle file), but probably they're outdated - it doesn't help.
Honestly it outrageous that IDE that supposed to think of such stuff instead of you...
I created a project with blank activity for API15 - Android 4.0.3 as minimal, I would very much appreciate if somebody will tell me how to get from here to the working blank application with successfully imported RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
 dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0
}
```

but if you use androidx you can try this

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, androidx works. It tells that 7:28.0.0 is legacy.